# mybitis run update sql error

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am using Spring and MyBatis, and getting a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` from a SQL update.

This is my Java src:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateEnv", method = { RequestMethod.POST})
@ResponseBody
public Result updateEnv(@RequestBody Map<String,Object> map){
    return envUserService.updateEnvById(map);
}
```

And my serviceImp:

```
clusterEnvMapper.updateClusterIdByEnvId(map);
```

This is my SQL mapping XML

```xml
<update id="updateClusterIdByEnvId" parameterType="java.util.Map" >
        update 
            nacha_cluster_env
        <trim prefix="SET" suffixOverrides=",">
            <if test="clusterId != null and clusterId != ''">
                CLUSTER_ID = #{clusterId,jdbcType=INTEGER},
            </if>
　　　　　　  <if test="clusterServiceIp != null and clusterServiceIp != ''">
                CLUSTER_SERVICE_IP = #{clusterServiceIp,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
            </if>
        </trim>
        where ENV_ID = #{envId,jdbcType=INTEGER}
</update>
```

but when I run it, I get this error:

```
17:05:44 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:317)-Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
17:05:44 INFO  [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory] (SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:127)-SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
七月 27, 2017 5:05:44 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
严重: Servlet.service() for servlet [service] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CLUSTER_SERVICE_IP = '40.125.203.202' 
where ENV_ID = 51' at line 6
### The error may involve cn.abcsys.cloud.devops.web.dao.ClusterEnvMapper.updateClusterIdByEnvId-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: update     nacha_cluster_env    SET CLUSTER_ID = ?,     　　　　　　      CLUSTER_SERVICE_IP = ?     where ENV_ID = ?
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CLUSTER_SERVICE_IP = '40.125.203.202' 
where ENV_ID = 51' at line 6
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CLUSTER_SERVICE_IP = '40.125.203.202' 
            where ENV_ID = 51' at line 6] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CLUSTER_SERVICE_IP = '40.125.203.202' 
            where ENV_ID = 51' at line 6
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4208)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2758)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2826)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1302)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.preparedStatement_execute(FilterChainImpl.java:2931)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterEventAdapter.preparedStatement_execute(FilterEventAdapter.java:440)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.preparedStatement_execute(FilterChainImpl.java:2929)
    at com.alibaba.druid.proxy.jdbc.PreparedStatementProxyImpl.execute(PreparedStatementProxyImpl.java:131)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledPreparedStatement.execute(DruidPooledPreparedStatement.java:493)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:45)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:73)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:49)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:115)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:354)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.update(SqlSessionTemplate.java:250)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:55)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:53)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.updateClusterIdByEnvId(Unknown Source)
    at cn.abcsys.cloud.devops.web.service.impl.EnvUserServiceImp.updateEnvById(EnvUserServiceImp.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.updateEnvById(Unknown Source)
    at cn.abcsys.cloud.devops.web.controller.EnvUserController.updateEnv(EnvUserController.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: howerer the sql : update  nacha_cluster_env   SET CLUSTER_ID = '22', CLUSTER_SERVICE_IP = '127.0.0.1'    where ENV_ID = 53   is effected

Comment: while  i find the sql is                 update nacha_cluster_env SET CLUSTER_ID = ?, 　　　　　　 CLUSTER_SERVICE_IP = ? where ENV_ID = ?    and   i find there is too much space cause this error . and i don't know this is  whether or not  mybitis error

Comment: I improved the grammar and formatting of this question.

Answer (score 0):

### I find this error is space.

so i delete all and write again ,it's avaliable.